# Upgraded to 1.9.2, now get: PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning

Tags: paypal, upgrade, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.9.2.0

So I am not sure if this is related but I have upgraded to 1.9.2 recently from 1.9.1 and now get this:

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

https://www.domain.com/paypal/ipn/

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you can verify that your IPNs are working for Magento orders, and that the URL is correct for your store, check that you aren't receiving IPNs for orders that Magento isn't aware of. For example, M2E orders set up with the same IPN URI. These will fail if Magento can't find the order for the IPN. If this is fine and your store is working properly, you can disable these notifications. If PayPal is disabling IPNs that you need, you will likely need to work with PayPal Merchant Technical Support to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What I have had to do everytime I reinstall magento is to go into configuration of the store and reconfigure the paypal checkout, redownload the pem key, and reinsert the api username and password.

some good pointers on how to debug what is going on
1. Click on those links they sent you, and see if you can actually access the links. mine are restricted in my ssl.conf file to a location match coming only from paypal, so i cant. maybe you have prevented the access some how
2. Try to debug the log files from your (apache, I am assuming, logs).  Mine are in /var/log/httpd/ and i have many different log files.  You can actually log into your paypal and resend the ipn notification. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNOperations/#id095RAI060Y4

I would do that and "tail -f" the log files to see what is added.

read more here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

and you can learn about testing your ipn here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/

It is also possible that your transactions are going through, but not notifying your magento system.

Have you ever thought about just calling paypal?

1 (402) 935-2050

honestly this is the only thing i would be doing, its also possible it could be a phishing scam